# How to encode inputs like artist or actor

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am currently developing a neural network that tries to make a suggestion for a specific user based on his recent activities. I will try to illustrate my problem with an example.

Now, let's say im trying to suggest new music to a user based on the music he recently listened to. Since people often listen to artists they know, one input of such a neural network might be the artists he recently listened to.

The problem is the encoding of this feature. As the id of the artist in the database has no meaning for the neural network, the only other option that comes to my mind would be one-hot encoding every artist, but that doesn't sound to promising either regarding the thousands of different artists out there.

My question is: How can i encode such a feature?

Comment: artist and genre ..

Comment: well, since genre is a categorical value, I could just use a one-hot encoding. Thats why i used "artist or actor" in the title.

Comment: You could learn a lower dimension encoding from one-hot encoding like word2vec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you describe is called [content-based filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system#Content-based_filtering). The intuition is to recommend items to customer A similar to previous items liked by A. An advantage to this approach is that you only need data about one user, which tends to result in a "personalized" approach for recommendation. But some disadvantages include the construction of features (the problem you're dealing with now), the difficulty to build an interesting profile for new users, plus it will also never recommend items outside a user's content profile. As for the difficulty of representation, features are usually handcrafted and abstracted afterwards. For music specifically, features would be things like 'artist', 'genre', etc. and abstraction for informative keywords (if necessary) is widely done using [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).

This may go outside the scope of the question, but I think it is also worth mentioning an alternative approach to this: [collaborative filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system#Collaborative_filtering). Rather than similar items, here we instead try to find users with similar tastes and recommend products that they liked. The only data you need here are some sort of user ratings or values of how much they (dis)liked some data - eliminating the need for feature design. Furthermore, since we analyze similar persons rather than items for recommendation, this approach tends to also work well for new users. The general flow for collaborative filtering looks like:

- Measure similarity between user of interest and all other users
- (optional) Select a smaller subset consisting of most similar users
- Predict ratings as a weighted combination of "nearest neighbors"
- Return the highest rated items

A popular approach for the similarity weighting in the algorithm is based on the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient).

Finally, something to consider here is the need for performance/scalability: calculating pairwise similarities for millions of users is not really light-weight on a normal computer.